# Ошибка Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double x = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
        double a = x / 1000;
        double b = x / 100 % 10;
        double c = x / 10 % 10;
        double d = x % 10;

        x = (a + b == c + d) ?label1.Text = "Сумма двух первых чисeл = сумме двух последних": label1.Text = "Сумма двух первых чисел не равна сумме двух последних";

    }
```

Comment: `if (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x)) { /* здесь прочая логика */} else { /* показать окно сообщения о невозможности преобразовать введеное число к типу Double */}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в неверном использовании тернарного оператора.

Тернарный оператор `(condition)? result1: result2` возвращает значение, в данном случае - возвращаемое значение имеет тип "string". Это значение присваивается переменной `x`, которая имеет тип `double`, отсюда и возникает ошибка указанная в вопросе.

Для решения достаточно заменить тернарный оператор на `if`

```
if (a + b == c + d) 
    label1.Text = "Сумма двух первых чисел = сумме двух последних";
else
    label1.Text = "Сумма двух первых чисел не равна сумме двух последних";
```

либо присваивать результат непосредственно в label:

```
label1.Text = (a + b == c + d) ? "Сумма двух первых чисел = сумме двух последних" : "Сумма двух первых чисел не равна сумме двух последних";
```